# Java: Mockito mocked class always call real method of parent class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

Trying to mock LDAP return data for testing.

For some reason the actual method is always called and return null. Confirm by debugging breakpoint.

I spend few hours trying to figure out the reason. It seem that the abstract class is causing me issue. I cannot change any of these classes. Am I looking for an impossible solution. Debugging is not simple...

Any pointers are welcome.

Maven dependencies...

```xml
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
            <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
```

```
############ Logging method invocation #2 on mock/spy ########
ldapConnectionPool.search(
    null,
    SUB,
    "(mail=a@b.c)"
);
    invoked: -> at package.Class.method(Class.java:228)
    has returned: "null"
```

Mocking class

```java
package com.unboundid.ldap.sdk;
public final class LDAPConnectionPool
       extends AbstractConnectionPool
```

AbstractConnectionPool called real method:

```java
  public final SearchResult search(final String baseDN, final SearchScope scope,
                                   final String filter,
                                   final String... attributes)
         throws LDAPSearchException
  {
    return search(new SearchRequest(baseDN, scope, parseFilter(filter),
         attributes));
  }
```

Test:

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class ClassTest {

    @MockBean
    private LdapConnectionPoolProvider ldapConnectionPoolProvider;

    private LDAPConnectionPool ldapConnectionPool= mock(LDAPConnectionPool.class, withSettings().verboseLogging());;

    @BeforeEach
    void beforeTest() {
        closeable= MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    @AfterEach
    void afterTest() throws Exception {
        closeable.close();
    }

    @Test
    void methodSuccess() throws LDAPSearchException {

        SearchResult res = new SearchResult(1243, ResultCode.SUCCESS, "", "", null, searchEntries, null, 0, 0, null);
        doReturn(res).when(ldapConnectionPool).search(any(String.class), any(SearchScope.class), any(String.class));

//calling method and mock instance of ldap
        SearchResult result = ldapConnectionPool.search(getBaseDN(), SearchScope.SUB, "(mail=" + getMail() + ")");
```

---

***UPDATES:***
I was able to reproduce and fix this issue with test.

I hope it can help someone else.

```java
@Slf4j
public class Tester {
    private LDAPConnectionPool ldapConnectionPool = mock(LDAPConnectionPool.class, withSettings().verboseLogging());

    private AutoCloseable closeable;
    @Mock
    private LdapAIOConnection ldapAIOConnection;

    @BeforeEach
    void init() {
        log.info("@BeforeEach - executes before each test method in this class");
    }

    @BeforeEach
    void beforeTest() {
        closeable = MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        doReturn(ldapConnectionPool).when(ldapAIOConnection).ldapConnectionPool();
    }

    @AfterEach
    void afterTest() throws Exception {
        closeable.close();
    }

    @Test
    void testIt() throws LDAPSearchException {
        List<SearchResultEntry> searchEntries = new ArrayList<>();
        String GUID = "??";
        String accControlCode = "512";
        String lastPassSet = "1234";

        Collection<Attribute> attrs = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(new Attribute("objectGUID", GUID),
            new Attribute("pwdLastSet", lastPassSet), new Attribute("userAccountControl", accControlCode)));
        searchEntries.add(new SearchResultEntry("", attrs, new Control("12")));

        SearchResult res = new SearchResult(1243, ResultCode.SUCCESS, "a.a.c", "a/a/a", null, searchEntries, null, 1, 1, null);
        //this fails
        //doReturn(res).when(ldapConnectionPool).search(any(String.class), any(SearchScope.class), any(String.class));

        //this pass
        doReturn(res).when(ldapConnectionPool).search(any(/*String.class*/), any(SearchScope.class), any(String.class));

        SearchResult result = ldapConnectionPool.search(null, SearchScope.SUB, "");
        Assertions.assertEquals(1, result.getEntryCount());

    }
}
```

Comment: Saldy to give a full example, I did a really small example and this one works. So somehow the test setup does breakdown the mock. Maybe Spring + Bean + Mock + ... ??
If I resolve it, I'll post a solution.

Comment: You haven't shown the code under test or where you call it in your test class.

Comment: `final` methods/classes cannot be mocked.  One solution is to have your own wrapper class which delegates to the actual class.   Then the wrapper class is used in the production code, and can also be mocked.  (This approach also abstracts the actual implementation and removes pollution of imports from all over the code base.)

Comment: Why are you calling `MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this)` in your `ClassTest`? There are no `@Mock`-annotated fields (nor any `@Spy` or `@InjectMocks` fields), so this call won't do anything. `@MockBean` is not part of Mockito, but part of Spring Boot. You usually don't want to mix the Mockito and the Spring Annotations in a single test.

Comment: @knittl thanks for the advice, I was really using both `@Mock` and `@MockBean`, just did not put all the code, nice catch.. Was not aware it was not recommended. I was able to remove the `@MockBean` by creating a `@Autowired` constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I guess I use SO as a chew toy.

In case someone has similar issue, this line cause the issue:

```java
SearchResult result = ldapConnectionPool.search(getBaseDN(), SearchScope.SUB, "(mail=" + getMail() + ")");
```

For some reason, I guess a distraction, the first parameter was null, getBaseDN() returns null. I assume the mock did not associate it to a String type and return null.

There is two solution fix the test:

1. Fix the getBaseDN to return a valid String
2. Change the first expected type in search, see below.

Change this:

```java
doReturn(res).when(ldapConnectionPool).search(any(String.class), any(SearchScope.class), any(String.class));
```

To this:

```java
doReturn(res).when(ldapConnectionPool).search(any(/*String.class*/), any(SearchScope.class), any(String.class));
```

I admit seeing lot of this suggestion on other SO answer but since setting all parameter to any() bring ambiguity...

A lesson learned is reduce the scope of the test, slowly add functionality until it break.